# visual studio copy paste bug

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

when i hit ctrl + c without selecting anything (it should copy that line) and make some changes in the code then paste to another section, however the copied code is no longer there. im using visual studio 2010 and 2008, they both have this bug. anyone else noticed this bug?

Comment: Perhaps you're running another app that uses the clipboard in an inappropriate fashion? http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?joel.3.555451.75

Comment: Do you happen to be using remote desktop?  The remote desktop clipboard viewer occasionally thwarts VS's attempts to place things on the clipboard.

Comment: nope not using remote desktop

Comment: I've tried it on VS 2008 running through a terminal server session  and it worked  fine.

Comment: Anyone any solution? It is simply annoying! This bug is coming several times randomly. The only thing helps to restart VS2010. The answers bellow did not help me.

Comment: Probably caused by a plugin in Visual Studio or external tool. Is the data still there when you copy and paste right away? Have you tried a clean install?

Comment: Does using ´ctrl + insert` and `shift + insert` work instead? (maybe it is another tool hooking the shortcuts ctrl + c/v)

Comment: add from a link only answer https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h3qMRma3EZQ

Answer (score 14):

I have VS2010, same problem. The culprit? I had Remote Desktop open.

Comment: This has been bugging me for weeks! I had the issue with vs 2013 and it was tight VNC that was causing the issues.

Comment: what was the solution!! broken link

Comment: Link is broken yes but. WTF! How come it's connected with remote desktop!!! And how come i can only find info about this here instead of Microsoft' web site, support service and Microsoft workers? Mark this as holy answer asap

Answer (score 8):

I had the same copy paste problem in vs2017 and i reset the keyboard shortcuts. Resharper the culprit.

Tools -> Options -> Search for keyboard(in search options) and click on Reset button.

[image]

Comment: Note: this issue seems on all version, I had it on VS2019, works like a charm as well.

Answer (score 2):

Ctrl+C & Ctrl+V on a line without any selection, does copy the line for me in VS2008 and VS2010.

Have you tried, Ctrl+X, then Ctrl+V, this should cut and paste the line back in the same place, but have the line contents in your clipboard buffer like using copy.

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced that problem before. In my case was a veeeeery simple explanation!
There is a shortcut of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+(<kbd>Supr</kbd> or <kbd>Ins</kbd>) that also work to copy and paste. So, in my case, when I did the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, and then modified some code before the paste, I used very often the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, and the <kbd>Begin</kbd> <kbd>End</kbd> , those keys are next to the <kbd>Supr</kbd> <kbd>Ins</kbd> keys, so what happened is I actually did other copy action (empty line) and when I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Paste</kbd> the clipboard was actually filled with the empty lines...  !  :)

Maybe you did not know the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd>+<kbd>Supr</kbd> shortcut to copy and paste and you are pressing that combination while modifying the code.

Hope that is your situation :)

Answer (score 2):

Try closing all code/class/form windows - then opening them up again. I found that Copy and Paste worked on some code windows, but not others.

Note: I had some extensions installed which bugged out, but I only saw the error message when I closed certain code windows.

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed this when I open the page I'm working on in the browser (right click anywhere in the page and choose "View in Browser").  As soon as I close the browser, copy and paste is restored.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in a new VS 2017 install on a Lenovo Thinkpad w/ Windows 10. In VS IDE, Tools -> Options->Keyboard , in the 'apply the following additional keyboard mapping scheme' dropdown (tried Default, no change) tried 'visual Studio Code' and clicked the 'Reset' button. I also changed the 'General -> color theme' from 'Blue' to 'Blue (high contrast) but I doubt that made a difference... so now Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V are working... Yay!

Answer (score 0):

Running VS2010, and same problem. All sorts of copy/paste errors (as in the title of the question). The culprit? I had Jumi Controller running. I killed the jumi.exe process, and all was back to normal.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: How does this not answer the question? How does the top rated answer differ from this?

Comment: The question seem to be: anyone else noticed this bug?  - yes.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting Visual Studio was a fix for me